# Access Denied error When trying to access a list in SharePoint from Infopath to create form

Tags: infopath

I have SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath 2013, I am not an administrator for SharePoint.

I need to create a New form in InfoPath, howvever, every time I try to get to the Data Connection Wizard, I get an error, Access Denied.

What permissions do I need to have on the SharePoint list, so that I can add / change / delete/ forms.

Comment: Full Control is required

Answer (score 0):

You would want to open the Data Connections window and select Add.
Select Receive and then select SharePoint Library or list
enter your main site http:// like you would for selecting libraries or lists.